# How to Add splash screen as well as Intro Screen in android?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean isStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart",true);
    if(!isStart){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeAcitivity.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                finish();
            }
        },3000);
    }
    else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    SharedPreferences.Editor e =getPrefs.edit();
    e.putBoolean("firstStart",false);
    e.apply();

}
```

}

I am a beginner in android app dev. I am trying to display Intro screen(using AppIntro library ) for first time when the user enters into the screen and from second time , the app should show a splash screen?

I am getting following error when i follows above code?

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-23386


    Process: gajapathy.com.volunteers, PID: 17022
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)` at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                                              at gajapathy.com.volunteers.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code it will work for you and modify little bit if its not fulfil your expectation

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{

                    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                    boolean isStart = getPrefs.getBoolean("firstStart",true);

                if (!isStart){
                        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeAcitivity.class);
                        startActivity(homeIntent);
                        finish();
                }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,IntroActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }

                SharedPreferences.Editor e =getPrefs.edit();
                e.putBoolean("firstStart",false);
                e.apply();
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Actually i need not sleep whenever i launches the app So i tried adding sleep () within the if condition . But i didn't get